# Qual é a finalidade dos objetos "request" e "response" de um framework web?

Tags: php, framework

Muitos frameworks que são baseados em rotas usam dois objetos no momento que ele executa a ação correspondente a rota.

Veja um exemplo no [Slim](http://www.slimframework.com/):

```
$app->get('/hello/{name}', function (Request $request, Response $response, array $args) {
    $name = $args['name'];
    $response->getBody()->write("Hello, $name");

    return $response;
});
```

Outro exemplo em [Silex](https://silex.symfony.com/doc/2.0/usage.html#example-post-route):

```
$app->post('/feedback', function (Request $request) {
    $message = $request->get('message');
    mail('feedback@yoursite.com', '[YourSite] Feedback', $message);

    return new Response('Thank you for your feedback!', 201);
});
```

Perceba que os objetos são `$request` e `$response`. Entretanto, eu ainda não consigo enter qual a finalidade deles alem do `$request` permitir a manipulação de parâmetros da URI em si. Sendo assim, gostaria de esclarecer minhas dúvidas.

## Dúvidas

- Qual é a finalidade dos objetos `$request` e `$response` no geral?
- O que eles representam numa requisição da aplicação?

Comment: Em resumo é "abstrair" a interface de HTTP de requisição e resposta para o proprio framework e provavelmente a ideia é até recriar elas ou manipulas a fim de poder até mesmo simular uma requisição diretamente no back-end, isso seria útil em cenários como testes unitários. Agora você pode ter certeza que vai aparecer respostas dizendo que isso "são boas práticas", mas em um frameworks PHP a ideia disto muitas vezes é exagerada, frameworks criados com o intuito de fazerem o serviço do Apache e do SAPI (Server API: apache2handler, fast-cgi, etc), muitos frameworks PHP simplesmente exageram [...]

Comment: [...] e acabam por serem tanques de guerra para matar formigas, o proprio PHP já se comunica com os SAPIs e trás para si o que é necessário dessa comunicação, então uma coisa é criar uma classe para facilitar pegar esses dados, outra é criar um abstração gigantesca exagerada que faz uma série de ciclos de leitura de coisas que você nem irá usar e o consumo de memória e processador vai nas alturas dependendo do numeros de requisições HTTP. Posso formular uma resposta, mas o que comentei aqui é algo fora do perguntando, uma critica as esses FWs modernos, que acho totalmente necessária.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento bom ver o seu comentário aqui. Ao meu ver não há nada de mal em "abstrair" a internface HTTP no PHP, mas realmente concordo com você que alguns frameworks exageraram demais ao fazê-lo. Acho que a desorganização interna do PHP (padrões de nome de funções, falta de recursos nativos) ajudaram a fazer com que existissem certos frameworks.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters não quero dizer que é mal abstrair, quero dizer que a forma e a ideia do conceito todo é péssima, mal pensada e um dev de um FW especifico resolve fazer e outros devs gostam e fazem e acaba por muitas vezes a escreverem coisas exageradas com intenção de tentar resolver TODOS PROBLEMAS do "mundo HTTP", quando a coisa poderia ser dividida em módulos e carregar somente o que é necessário, mas os DEVs pensam em querer resolver tudo e a coisa só vai ladeira abaixo :)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Em resumo, gastam uma energia absurda para remendar o PHP que provavelmente seria melhor usada pra aprender outra linguagem em vez de aprender um FW. Penso que quem é pragmático use PHP como o PHP foi concebido, com pequenos ajustes, ou então escolhe outra tecnologia que não precise remendar tanto.

Comment: @Bacco sim, as pessoas procuraram facilidades e acabam sacrificando muita coisa, eu já disse e torno a dizer, esses frameworks perdem muito feito em performance para outras tecnologias voltadas a web (fora do mundo php), ai as pessoas culpam os servidores ou os clientes por não quererem contratar um "amazon-like" da vida em sites pequenos e médios, mas se negam a culpar as "tecnologias" PHP (frameworks e CMSs por ai). As pessoas ficam ofendidas quando digo que isso é tudo muito mal planejado e que por não entenderem acabam por querer compensar as falhas de outras maneiras (gastos)

Comment: @Bacco ouso dizer que raramente as pessoas usam todo o "potencial" ou realmente vão precisar de tudo que tem nesses FWs, na verdade vejo alguns que acabam criando as coisas na mão, mesmo tendo o FW ali. Ai me *pergunto, "pra que tanta firula na agrupada se muitas coisas as pessoas resolvem de forma manual e as vezes até simples?"*. É muita justificativa forçada dos devs desses FW para coisas que no final não se justificam, pois muita coisa as pessoas acabam por fazer de outras maneiras. :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu já tive a oportunidade de construir alguns frameworks em linguagens como PHP e Python, bem como já olhei bastante como funciona o código-fonte deles.

Basicamente, podemos entender que a ideia dos frameworks é abstrair cada coisa. E isso não é diferente com a requisição e a resposta.

Toda requisição feita por um cliente web passa pela etapa da requisição e da resposta. E essa é a ideia por trás do Silex, Slim e outros frameworks.

Os maioria dos frameworks utilizaram a classe `Request` para representar a requisição vinda do cliente. Pode ser que isso varie entre um objeto vindo do parâmetro de um método ou de um factory, mas no final a finalidade sempre é representar a requisição do cliente.

Nele, deve haver informações importantes para o seu backend trabalhar, como por exemplo:

- Parâmetros de query string ou payload.
- Tipo de conteúdo requisitado, através do Content-Type ou Accept.
- Método da requisição e afins.

Essas informações, é claro, não dependem do framework. Elas estão disponíveis no PHP, como por exemplo, na variável `$_SERVER` com valores prefixados por `HTTP_`.

Por sua vez, a classe `Response` facilita bastante a abstração da resposta enviada para o navegador. Pode parecer simples, mas quando você pensa numa estrutura do framework, você precisa estruturar muito bem o que é enviado ao cliente. Um exemplo disso é o fato da saída do browser não poder ser definida antes dos headers. No caso, com o framework você poderia, por exemplo, chamar a definição dos headers depois da definição do que será o output, pois internamente, o framework empilhará a resposta e organizará como tudo será enfiado ao browser.

Além disso, a ideia de ter uma classe de resposta é poder "encurtar" o máximo possível a quantidade de códigos que você vai digitar.

Por exemplo, um framework poderia ter o método `$response->json()`, interamente transformando os dados de saída para o formato `JSON` e definindo o `header` necessário para que o browser entenda sua resposta nesse formato.

Tudo se resume na abstração, como citado pelo Guilherme Nascimento nos comentários. Não é nada que você já não possa fazer com o "PHP puro".

No meu ponto de vista, há vantagens e desvantagens, mas são coisas que você automaticamente assume a responsabilidade por aceitar ou não usar um framework.

## Comentando alguns pontos da pergunta

> Muitos frameworks que são baseados em rotas usam dois objetos no momento que ele executa a ação correspondente a rota.

Isso é porque basicamente toda o ciclo da requisição se baseia em uma **requisição** e uma **resposta**. Os dois parâmetros representa a abstração de cada um deles, podendo ter ferramentas que facilite acesso a alguams coisas.

Por exemplo, PHP puro, para decidir se vai responder com JSON ao cliente caso ele solicite isso pelo header `Accept`, você teria que verificar se o valor `application/json` está presente na variável `$SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT']`. Já no Framework Laravel, você poderia simplesmente chamar `$request->isJson()` ou `$request->wantsJson()`.

Se quiser ir além nos exemplos, podemos comentar ainda o caso do Silex (uma pena que foi depreciado), que usa a classe `Response` para representar uma resposta.

Por padrão, essa classe `Response` do Silex responde com o valor passado como string no primeiro parâmetro, sendo possível definir status da requisição e headers extras (coisa que alguns iniciantes poderiam ter dificuldades em fazer facilmente). Sem contar que existe classes que podem derivadas de `Response`, como `JsonResponse`, que teria como objetivo retornar a resposta já formatada para o cliente (já comentei isso anteriormente acima).

Essas abstrações tem como objetivo criar operações comuns e agrupá-las, como forma de facilitar a vida do programador - *há quem discorde :)*.

## PSR-7

Se tiver curiosidade, pode dar uma olhada no [PSR-7](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-7/). A ideia parece estar voltada para dar um norte aos desenvolvedores de bibliotecas sobre como criar as abstrações das etapas da requisição.